# Why do Java Interface method parameters need declaration IDs?

Tags: java, interface, named-parameters

The question sums it up.

In C++ you can declare an interface method with a parameter list of just types, but in Java you need to associate a variable name with the type. I understand that this increases readability, but it would be great if this was optional. The parameter names do not even have to match the implementation names, so why bother naming them in the interface?

```
public interface Foo() {
  setName(String, String) // Why can't this be enough?
}

public class FooImpl implements Foo {
  private String name = "";

  @override
  setName(String fname, String lname) {
    this.name = String.format("%s %s", fname, lname);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's necessarily an answer beyond "because that's how the language is defined"...

Comment: I guess the designers of the language would make something more readable.

Comment: This has in fact been discussed on SO earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998151/why-do-we-need-to-specify-parameter-name-in-interface

Comment: The only reason that comes to my mind is enabling [Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) integration.

Comment: The names are required for Javadocs.  The parameters are matched by names in the documentation.  Without names you wouldn't know what any of the parameters were for. If you are using an IDE, it can use the names to fill in the generated implementation stubs.  They are useful if not directly.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: there are actually several. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998151/why-do-we-need-to-specify-parameter-name-in-interface