# How to remove all C# methods/properties/fields "summary" comments (starting with ///) in current document in Visual Studio with one shot?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to remove all C# methods/properties/fields "summary" comments

(starting with `///`)

in current document in Visual Studio with one shot?

In other words convert this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Very stupid comment generated with very stupid tool
/// </summary>
protected void MyMethod
{

}
```

Into this:

```
protected void MyMethod
{

}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for quick replace
- Mark `Use` : `Regular expressions`
- Enter in `Find what` field following expression `^.*\/\/\/.*$\n` (shortly - line with `///` pattern)
- Leave `Replace with` field empty
- Make sure that you `Look in` in `Current Document`
- Click `Replace All`

Comment: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 5):

Regex pattern `^.*\/\/\/ ?<summary>.*\n(?:^.*\/\/\/.*$\n)*` will be more suitable in this case because it will match whole summary comment at once.

- `^.*\/\/\/ ?<summary>.*\n` - matches line with `/// <summary>` text (with optional space after slashes)
- `(?:)+` - non-capturing group, repeated zero or more times
- `^` - beginning of the line
- `.*` - any characters
- `\/\/\/` - three slashes
- `.*` - any characters
- `$` - end of line
- `\n` - line break symbol

Comment: this is the real answer for removing the summary comments!